# Add calculateditems

Tags: excel, vba

I keep getting an error 1004 with this code:

```
Dim PT As PivotTable
For Each Data_sht In Worksheets
    If Data_sht.Name <> "Raw Data" Then
    Set PT = Data_sht.PivotTables(1)
    PT.PivotFields("InvYear").CalculatedItems.Add Name:="Growth", Formula:="='2015'-'2014'"
    With PT.PivotFields("InvYear").PivotItems("Growth")
        .Position = 3
        .Caption = "Growth"
    End With
    End If
Next Data_sht
```

I have pivot items name `2015` and `2014` under `InvYear` field as a column label. I am trying to calculate the difference between two columns but I keep getting error, or when it runs it deletes all the values in the PivotTable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible that `InvYear` isn't present. Take a look at this example:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim PT As PivotTable

    Dim NewFieldName As String, YearFieldName As String, SheetToIgnore As String
    NewFieldName = "GrowthTest"
    YearFieldName = "Year"
    SheetToIgnore = "Sheet1"

    For Each Data_sht In Worksheets
        If Data_sht.Name <> SheetToIgnore Then
            Set PT = Data_sht.PivotTables(1)
            PT.PivotFields(YearFieldName).CalculatedItems.Add Name:=NewFieldName, Formula:="='2015'-'2014'"
            With PT.PivotFields(YearFieldName).PivotItems(NewFieldName)
                .Position = 3
                .Caption = NewFieldName
            End With
        End If
    Next Data_sht
End Sub
```

Note how my sheet1 looks:

[image: Sheet1]

Note how my sheet3 looks like before running code

[image: Sheet3 before]

Note how my sheet3 looks like after running code

[image: Sheet3 after]

The code runs cleanly. Hopefully you could adapt this code to your scenario and get everything working.